# Please build project before executing SonarQube and check the location of compiled classes

Tags: android, sonarqube, lint

I am executing sonar-runner on my Android project, and get this error:

```
Android Lint needs sources to be compiled. Please build project before executing SonarQube and check the location of compiled classes.
```

My project is already built, classes are in `bin/classes`.

How to solve this?

My `sonar-project.properties`:

```
sonar.projectKey=anki:AnkiDroid
sonar.projectName=AnkiDroid
sonar.projectVersion=1.0
sonar.sources=src
sonar.language=java
sonar.sourceEncoding=UTF-8
sonar.profile=Android Lint
```

Answer (score 2):

Add this line to your `sonar-project.properties`:

```
sonar.binaries=bin/classes
```

It solves the problem.